# install alphacep(VOSK APİ) Python

Tags: python, speech-to-text, vosk

Remembrances. I https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api I'm trying to set it up, but I can't, can anyone set it up before ?

Comment: Please provide more details and I'll be happy to help you. The install is usually simple `pip3 install vosk`

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vosk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vosk

Comment: Ok, what platform you are trying. What is your python3 version, what is your pip3 version?

Comment: you can also join our telegram to get faster help.

Comment: telegram username: @VoskApi

Comment: our telegram is on https://t.me/speech_recognition_help

Answer (score 0):

From doc (https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install):

> On Windows make sure you have 64-bit Python. We do not support 32-bit python yet.